# Mono Linker MarkException Error Processing Method

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I got this error when use `Xamarin.Form` version > 4.7

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Mono.Linker.MarkException: Error processing method: 'System.Void xxx.Droid.Resource::UpdateIdValues()' in assembly: 'xxx.Droid.dll' ---> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve System.Int32 Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.Resource/String::overflow_tab_title
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.HandleUnresolvedField(FieldReference reference)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkInstruction(Instruction instruction)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethodBody(MethodBody body)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessMethod(MethodDefinition method)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessPrimaryQueue()
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process()
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
   at MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
   at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.ProcessStep(LinkContext context, IStep step)
   at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
   at MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process(LinkerOptions options, ILogger logger, LinkContext& context)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.RunTask()
   at Microsoft.Android.Build.Tasks.AndroidTask.Execute() in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/xamarin-android-tools/src/Microsoft.Android.Build.BaseTasks/AndroidTask.cs:line 17 xxx.Droid
```

I have tried to

1. Remove Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter
2. Clean -> close vs -> remove bin / obj folder -> start vs -> rebuild

But still no luck. When I tried to use version 4.7 its fine. But when I tried to use > 4.7 the error comes. Any idea?

Comment: Have you checked the [dependencies](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms#dependencies-body-tab) of the latest Xamarin.Forms package? Sometimes it's necessary to update the dependencies manually for Android.

Comment: You can try to open the nuget package manager of the android project and then update all the installed packags to the newer version.